# Compute $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_1^\infty e^{-k/\sqrt x} \cos(k+x^2) \ dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Compute $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_1^\infty e^{-k/\sqrt x} \cos(k+x^2) \ dx.$$

For $k =10$ the integrand looks like

[image]

If I let $f_k(x) = e^{-k/\sqrt x} \cos(k+x^2)$, then I have $f_k(x) \le e^{-k/\sqrt x} = \frac{1}{e^{k/\sqrt x}}$ and $\frac{1}{e^{k/\sqrt x}} \to 0$, when $k \to \infty$. Should I try to use the dominated convergence theorem here? From what I got it would seem that $|f_k(x)|$ would converge pointwise to $0$, but I don't have a dominating function for $f_k$?

Comment: Take $u = x^2/k^4$. To estimate the integrals of $u^{-1/2} \exp(-u^{-1/4}) \sin(k^4 u)$ and $u^{-1/2} \exp(-u^{-1/4}) \cos(k^4 u)$, apply integration by parts and use the fact that $\int_0^\infty u^p \exp(-u^{-1/4}) \, du$ exists for $p < -1$.