# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n/\sqrt{x}} \cos(n+x^2) \,dx $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I came across the problem stated above on a course on measure theory. I think I should use some convergence theorem to be able to take the limit inside the integral, but I feel completely stuck. Would it be possible to use dominated or monotone convergence theorems to compute the limit, or is there some different approach that I should use?

Comment: The functions aren't integrable on $(1, \infty)$ (note that $\exp(-n / \sqrt x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$)

Comment: Since $\cos(n+x^2)$ ocsillates increasingly rapidly as $x \to \infty$ the *improper* integral is going to exist.

Comment: Wouldn’t the exponential be $0$ as the graph converges to $e^{-\frac n{\sqrt x}}\to0 ,n\to\infty$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash As $x \to \infty$, $-n/\sqrt x \to 0$ and $e^{-n/\sqrt x} \to 1$.

Comment: See the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4276378).

Comment: @Maxim Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Maxim thanks for pointing out the comment on the other post! Could you please elaborate more on how to continue after doing the integration by parts? When doing the integration by parts the second terms are going to be of the same form as in your comment. However, aren't there going to also be terms of the form $u^{1/2} \int e^{-u^{-1/4}}cos(n^4u)$? How could I take the limits of these?

Comment: Please show your work. The improper integral $\int_{u_0}^\infty u^{1/2} \exp(-u^{-1/4}) \cos n u \, du$ diverges, so there has to be an incorrect step somewhere in your derivation.